# In M theory, can a fundamental open string attach to a M5 brane?

Tags: string-theory, branes

I only saw a couple of pages online that showed this so i guess I'll ask on here, can fundamental open 1 string end on an M5 brane?

Answer (score 2):

There are no fundamental strings in M-theory. M2 branes can end on M5 branes and these appear as strings in the world volume of the M5 branes but these strings are of solitonic nature.